# Can you protect a python variable with exec()?

Tags: python

This is kind of a hacky Python question.

Consider the following Python code:

```py
def controlled_exec(code):
  x = 0
  def increment_x():
    nonlocal x
    x += 1

  globals = {"__builtins__": {}} # remove every global (including all python builtins)
  locals = {"increment_x": increment_x} # expose only the increment function

  exec(code, globals, locals)

  return x
```

I expect this function to provide a controlled code API, which simply counts the number of `increment_x()` calls. I tried it and I get the correct behavior.

```py
# returns 2
controlled_exec("""\
increment_x()
increment_x()
""")
```

I assume this way of doing is not secure, but I wonder out of curiosity. Can I set `x` to an arbitrary value (say negative) by executing code via `controlled_exec(...)` ? How would I do that?

Comment: You're correct, [this is not secure](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: Do you want to define a function like `decrement_x`?

Comment: So is this just a toy example, or are you really thinking about implementing something like this? In the latter case, I can think of other, more secure approaches depending on what you're trying to do; beware the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: (in keeping with wjandrea's comment above: it's a lot easier to build a parser and interpreter for a mini-language and keep _that_ sandboxed than to sandbox Python; moreover, the former has already been done, and there are implementations ready to use)

Comment: Those are great comments thank you! I wasn't sure how to formulate the problem I'm facing but yes, in the end I want a sandboxed code environment with a restricted API. Ideally, I'd like to keep the python language though. @CharlesDuffy could you point me to one of these implementations?

Comment: @Bix I don't know how current the answers are, but this question may be helpful: [Is there a "safe" subset of Python for use as an embedded scripting language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/861864/11082165)

Comment: My suggestion was more along the lines of embedding languages that aren't actually Python -- personally I'm a fan of LISP-y languages in places where simplicity is a foremost consideration; Norvig's [`lispy`](https://norvig.com/lispy.html), f/e, is around 120 lines in full (granted, it's more a toy than [its successor](https://norvig.com/lispy2.html), which still stays under a kloc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `x` can be set to an arbitrary value by code executed by `controlled_exec`.

Consider the following demo:

```
def controlled_exec(code):
  x = 0
  def increment_x():
    nonlocal x
    x += 1
    print(f"{x=}")

  globals = {"__builtins__": {}} # remove every global (including all python builtins)
  locals = {"increment_x": increment_x} # expose only the increment function

  exec(code, globals, locals)

  return x


controlled_exec("""\
increment_x()
increment_x.__closure__[0].cell_contents = -100
increment_x()
""")
```

This outputs

```
x=1
x=-99
```

This is really no way to "secure" `exec`. No matter what you do, at the end of the day you're executing arbitrary Python code, which is just as free to access and modify the state of the Python interpreter as the code that you write.

To highlight just how difficult it would be meaningfully secure `exec`, note that despite your attempt to hide builtins from the executed code, an attacker can still access any builtin via

```
increment_x.__globals__['__builtins__']
```

This is just one of dozens of tricks that someone trying to exploit this function could use.

The fact that we can modify the variable `x` is really a tame example. There's literally nothing stopping the code passed to `controlled_exec` from doing more disastrous things, like wiping your hard drive or downloading malware.